# Trouble Deserializing XML into Object properties end up null

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, deserialization, xml-serialization

I am working on a handling a response from a SOAP web service call. When the method in the client object tries to deserialize the response, it is nothing.

I have set up a test to emulate the deserialization process, but still cannot get the values for IsSuccess and Message to populate in the object.

Please help me out here to determine what is missing, so the deserialization process will completely deserialize the xml into the corresponding object. The contract code is auto generated using svcutil.

EDIT: I can manipulate the xml as needed with a messageinspector, so if the issue is with the xml I just need to figure out what to change.

Contract clases:

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.0.30319.33440"),
 System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="Green:EggsandHam.wsdll")>
Partial Public Class NumberResponse

    Private isSuccessField As String

    Private messageField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order:=0)>
    Public Property IsSuccess() As String
        Get
            Return Me.isSuccessField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.isSuccessField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order:=1)>
    Public Property Message() As String
        Get
            Return Me.messageField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.messageField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0"),
 System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced),
 System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped:=False)>
Partial Public Class NumberResponse1

    <System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute([Namespace]:="Green:EggsandHam.wsdl", Order:=0)>
    Public NumberResponse As NumberResponse

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal NumberResponse As NumberResponse)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.NumberResponse = NumberResponse
    End Sub
End Class
```

Test:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim u As New NumberResponse1()
        u = Deserialize(Of NumberResponse1)(XElement.Load("C:\test\number.xml"))
        Console.WriteLine(u.NumberResponse.Message)
    End Sub

    Public Function Deserialize(Of T)(ByVal xElement As XElement) As T
        Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xElement.ToString()))
            Dim xmlSerializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
            Return xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream)
        End Using
    End Function

End Module
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NumberResponse1>
    <NumberResponse>
        <ns1:NumberResponse xmlns:ns1="Green:EggsandHam.wsdl">
            <ns1:IsSuccess>true</ns1:IsSuccess>
            <ns1:Message>number processed successfully.</ns1:Message>
        </ns1:NumberResponse>
    </NumberResponse>
</NumberResponse1>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue by reverse engineering, I serialized the classes to xml. The new xml ended up looking like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NumberResponse1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <NumberResponse>
        <IsSuccess xmlns="Green:EggsandHam.wsdl">True</IsSuccess>
        <Message xmlns="Green:EggsandHam.wsdl">your father smelt of elderberries</Message>
    </NumberResponse>
</NumberResponse1>
```

It was missing the xmlschema namespaces.